# django redirect under post statement doesn't work

Tags: html, css, django

This is the exmaple code that works, or any other if statements

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    return render(request, 'Page-2.html')

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Page-1.html')
```

But when I change the redirect under a request.method =='POST' statement, it doesn't redirect the page, but the print works

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('test')
        return redirect('home')

    return render(request, 'Page-2.html')

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Page-1.html')
```

The original code was just for login and redirect the page, did I miss something to set up? thanks!

----update---

It was the problem of the html class, the html was generate by an app called nicepage, deleting the class fixed it, not familiar with the html and css, the class was pointed to css file, I don't know why a css class will cause this problem

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="u-clearfix u-form-horizontal u-form-spacing-15 u-inner-form" style="padding: 19px;" source="custom">
```

Comment: It was the Html problem, fixed it by changing one, the Html was generated by other program, though I don't know why that html doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me. not sure if this will help but this is my login view.

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

    if request.POST:
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            usr_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

            if not usr_profile.email_verified:
                messages.warning(request, gettext("Account is not verified!"))
                request.session['user_id'] = user.id
                return redirect('verify-email')

            if usr_profile.totp:
                request.session['user_id'] = user.id
                return redirect('verify-totp-login')
            else:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, gettext("Login successfully !"))
                return redirect('user-dashboard')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    requested_verification = False
    user_id = request.session.get('user_id')
    if user_id:
        try:
            usr_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(request, gettext('Unknown error occurred!'))
            return redirect('login')
        if not usr_profile.email_verified:
            requested_verification = True

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'requested_verification': requested_verification,
    }

    return render(request, 'main/authentication/login.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because You are not putting any content inside it,
It will redirect you if you will authenticate user..

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "You have logged in!")
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, "Your account is disabled!")
                return redirect('/login')
        return render(request, 'Page-2.html')
```

Comment: That is not the problem, the code was simplified to a minimum reproducible example, please look at the code clearly, it has nothing to do with content.